# Probability of rare events with some time parameter

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

While trying to $solve$  a simple problem involving probability theory, I run in some difficulties. The question is simple:

A type of earthquake is verified to occur in the long run once in $50$ years with probability of $75 \%.$ What's the probabilty that it will occur once in $10$ years ?

I first thought to use the Bayesian statistics on conditional probabilities, but I could not convince myself. I could not formulate apropriately the given data and adapt it to the required data for the Bayesien formula.

I then $thought$ of the Poisson distribution, which might eventually model the occurrence of rare events with a time parameter. I did not find an indication though that such an earthquake will follow the Poisson distribution.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for here, this doesn't sound like a math problem.  It sounds like a modeling problem.  To decide if the process is well modeled by Poisson, say, you need to review the historical data.  Is it true that the probability is constant over fixed time intervals?  That's a data question, not a math question.

Answer (score 2):

if the rate of poisson distribution is  lambda
probability of occurring of earthquake in time t  is P(X >= 1)
= 1- P(X = 0)
= 1 - e^(-lambda * t)

now it is given for t = 50

1 - e^(-lambda * 50)   = 0.75
 e^(-lambda * 50) = 0.25
find  lambda from this equation.

and  you need to find  the probability for t = 10

hence required probability is

1 - e^(-lambda * 10)
just substitute the value of lambda from above.

Thanks

Comment: put k = 0 to get P(X = 0 ) = e^(- lambda * t)  , note that  i am using lambda as rate .  parameter is lambda * t

Comment: The Poisson distribution is defined by $P(X=k)=\frac{{\lambda}^k \cdot  e^{-\lambda}}{k!}.$ I dont understand the fact that you plug in the time $t$ in the exponent of $\lambda.$ Can you explain how ?

Comment: in your formula lambda will be some constant into time. , i took lambda as rate only

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution  , then see the sub-topic   Probability of events for a Poisson distribution